# PHP: Last file in directory

Tags: php, file

How do I get the name of the last file (alphabetically) in a directory with php? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the [Directories](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php) extension you can do it simply with

```
$all_files = scandir("/my/path",1);
$last_files = $all_files[0];
```

Comment: `scandir()` does not specify *which* sorting it uses, so your results may be inaccurate if you have files with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: One would expect it to be the same sort sort() does, using the string option.

Comment: @Ignacio: According to http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php, the 'default sort order is alphabetical in ascending order'

Comment: @cb160: What does "alphabetical" mean when you mix German, Japanese, and Korean?

Answer (score 2):

The [scandir](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) command returns an array with the list of files in a directory. The second parameter specifies the sort order (defaults to ascending, 1 for descending).

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
$last_file = $files[0];
print($last_file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Code here looks like it would help](http://www.laughing-buddha.net/jon/php/dirlist/) - would just need to use end($array) to collect the last value in the generated array.

Comment: hm, other answers are much neater.

Comment: Why make me click the link to see your advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = scandir('path/to/dir');
sort($files, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
array_pop($files);
```